# In the Hanafi view, after my husband said the triple talaq in anger, am I now divorced with no hope of reconciliation?

Tags: talaq, hanafi

During a period of anger, my husband said the triple talaq. As a revert, I didn't understand the consequence of what he was saying and I've had to Google this. Is it really true that I'm now divorced with no hope of reconciliation?

I was drawn to the beauty of Islam by it's fairness, reading book after book on how fair Islam is to women and how we we are given more rights than are given in society and the Catholic faith I came from.  Please can someone clarify this for me and offer some explanation on how this protects women.  This has really knocked my faith.

Comment: is this according to the hanafi school of thought too?

Comment: You should edit your question and title to explain that you are looking for the hanafi view.

Comment: Anger may mean he was not knowing what he said if so then no you wouldn't be divorced, but the right place to ask is a scholar and your husband should ask him!

Comment: there are general (not only for hanafi) versions of the question: [A list of 24 questions about triple talaq](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/a-list-of-24-questions-about-triple-talaq)

Answer (score 1):

For such a critical ruling you should consult a Mufti to give you the correct verdict taking into account all the relevant details ... for example the wording and the intention plays a part.

According to the Hanafis, and AFFAIK most of the classical scholars ... three divorces in a single go are effective and come into force.

From the Hanafi text [Hidayah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Hidayah) (view [here](https://archive.org/stream/Hedaya_201703/Hedaya#page/n325/mode/2up)):

> **Talaq al-bidah** (innovation conflicting with the Sunnah) is that he divorce her with **three repudiations pronounced in a single
>   statement** or three repudiations in a single period of purity. If he
>   does this, **the divorce takes effect**, but he has sinned. Al-Shafi`i
>   (God bless him) said that each form of divorce is mubah (permissible)
>   as it is a legally valid act so that it leads to its legal effects.

From the Hanafi Tafsir [Ahkamul Quran by Abu Bakr Al-Jassas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Ja%E1%B9%A3%E1%B9%A3%C4%81s) (view arabic [here](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=201&idto=201&bk_no=212&ID=117)):

> قوله (تعالى): الطلاق مرتان فإمساك بمعروف أو تسريح بإحسان ؛ الآية؛ يدل
>   على وقوع الثلاث معا؛ مع كونه منهيا عنه؛
>
> [my translation] The verse [2:229](https://quran.com/2/229) " لطَّلَاقُ مَرَّتَانِ ۖ فَإِمْسَاكٌ بِمَعْرُوفٍ
>   أَوْ تَسْرِيحٌ بِإِحْسَانٍ " gives proof for the validity and enforcement of three
>   divorces given together.

From [Tafsir Qurtubi](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=5&tSoraNo=2&tAyahNo=229&tDisplay=yes&Page=3&Size=1&LanguageId=1) (Maliki scholar, but mentions the majority view and doesn't mention a dissent for the Hanafis):

> قال علماؤنا: وٱتفق أئمة الفتوى على لزوم إيقاع الطلاق الثلاث في كلمة
>   واحدة؛ وهو قول جمهور السلف، وشذّ طاوس وبعض أهل الظاهر إلى أن طلاق
>   الثلاث في كلمة واحدة يقع واحدة
>
> [my translation] Our Ulema say: The Imams of Fatwah are agreed on the matter that
>   giving three divorces in one statement makes them binding and this is
>   the saying of the majority of the Salaf. And Tawus and some of the Ahl-e-Zahir
>   said that giving three together enforces one divorce.

Also see [islamweb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=82330):

> However, if one delivers three divorces at once by saying an
>   expression such as: "You are divorced thrice", without repeating the
>   expression (I divorce you), then the Muslim Scholars differed in this
>   case. Imams **Abu Haneefah**, Malik, Shafi’i, Ahmad and the majority of
>   the Muslim Scholars **consider this kind of divorce as divorcing three
>   times** ...
>
> However, Imam Tawoos, Ibn Taymiyah and other contemporary Scholars
>   consider it as only one divorce.

Regarding the state of anger, it does not effect the divorce unless the anger was of such an extreme nature that it reached lunacy, see [Radd al Muhtar](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=27&ID=157&idfrom=2350&idto=2640&bookid=27&startno=19), and the approximate translation [here](http://www.daruliftaa.com/node/5627), again this is something you should elaborate to a Mufti and he will guide you further.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radd_al-Muhtar_ala_al-Dur_al-Mukhtar

Comment: first 2 quotations do not show clearly whether triple talaq at once is counted as 1 talaq or as 3 talaqs. 3rd quotation is of maliki scholar, so it is not enough. 4rd quote is from a modern website's own text, and there is no prooflinks in it, and even authors of the text is not shown!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in Hanafi three talaaqs does fall whether said in jest or anger. It is the most disliked form of talaaq and is to be used only in extreme circumstances. 
It is a fair ruling meant to make both parties value the seriousness of nikaah and that is it not to be taken lightly as would be the case if there was continuous talaaq and nikaah with no repercussions. 
I am so sorry for you.
When Allah takes you out of something, it is to replace you with better-that is faith.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We are not a typical an internet forum. Therefore we expect answers to be well elaborated, see "[how to answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" for more information. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model.